# Merge function in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, concurrenthashmap, bifunctor

Got a question about the merge function with ConcurrentHashMaps. New to functional programming so not sure if I'm utilizing it correctly.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-

```
map.merge(consumer, val, (a, b) -> (a.date().compareTo(b.date())) >= 0 ? a : b);
```

What it should do if I've reasoned it out correctly is `insert (consumer, val)` into the table if there is no existing entry. If there is, then it should compare the dates of a and b (value in table and my val). If "val" is > than the entry in the table, it should replace it with that. Otherwise, stick with existing entry.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok, but you can always write a simple test case to check your logic

Comment: I’d remove the obsolete brace pair around `a.date().compareTo(b.date())` for the readability’s sake. Besides that, it looks fine. Alternatively, you can use `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.date()))` or with `YourType::date` instead of `x -> x.date()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one example,

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "one");
map.put(2, "two");

map.merge(1, "newOne", (v1, v2) -> v1 + ", " + v2);
```

The third remapping function is used when there's a key conflict. Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is
>   associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.
>   Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given
>   remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may
>   be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key.